# Error submitting Mac app - "The product archive package's signature is invalid"

Tags: xcode, macos

I am trying to upload my Mac app 
But when I submit or validate the archive there is always the following error showing:

The product archive package's signature is invalid. Ensure that it is signed with your "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" certificate.

What I have to do?
Thanks

Comment: Are you having trouble with the keys, or are you asking with help about setting the keys in the build settings?

Comment: I fixed it. I had to sign it with terminal Thanks

Comment: Really? I don't think that's necessarily the fix to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post and it worked for me:

> My problem was that I had installed Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion (it doesn't work anyway, but that's another story). This corrupted the productutil app.
>
> To fix it: install the BSD.pkg in the Packages folder of your Lion Installer.

Comment: If this is not your solution, please **provide a link** back to the source where you found this information.

Comment: I had the exact same problem running Xcode 5.1.1 on Yosemite and the solution works, as I also had tried unsuccesfully to get Xcode 3.2.6 running on Yosemite. Just install BSD.pkg from the System/Installation/Packages folder from your Yosemite installation CD.